# How to know which link from one and the same linklabel was right clicked in the context menu?

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip, linklabel

I have a `LinkLabel` to which a context menu strip is attached. This context menu has 2 options: 'Copy hyperlink' or 'Open hyperlink'. There is no problem when there is only one link in the link label. But I can't figure out how you can (if you can) know which link out of the `Links` property in the link label is right clicked. This is what I have that works for a single link:

```
private void contextMenuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    ContextMenuStrip item = sender as ContextMenuStrip;
    LinkLabel tempLink = item.SourceControl as LinkLabel;
    if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "&Open Hyperlink")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tempLink.Links[0].LinkData.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(tempLink.Links[0].LinkData.ToString());
    }
}
```

Some help on how to know which of the `Links` is clicked would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use click event and type folloing code
LinkLabel llb = (LinkLabel)sender;
now llb.Text has text on which u click the linklabel.

Comment: I can't really remember asking this question :p I'll just accept this and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do that.
Quick one is the `opening` event on the context menu strip. In that sender will be whatever was right clicked on.

You could just store it as say currentLinkLabel, or you could set the `Tag` property of the menu item maybe

Comment: The `ContextMenuStrip` does not have a `Popup` event. You're talking about the `ContextMenu`